# Server 2016 TP5 change language

Tags: windows-server-2016

I have a TP5 english image and installed the german language with the language pack image over lpksetup. Now I wanted to switch to german and changed every language setting but still the names and descriptions from features and roles in ServerManager are still in english.
After this I installed an german image to verify if the features and roles are always in english but they were in german.
So I hope someone has an idea.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Okay I did not get it working with TP5 but with the Evaluation version I did the following:

I added the language over the GUI and downloaded the language pack over the "Options" button.

Then i executed the following CMDlets:

```
Set-WinUserLanguageList de-DE -Force
Set-Culture de-DE
Set-WinHomeLocation -GeoId 94
Set-WinsystemLocale de-DE
```

After this I see that the system downloads the "german handwritings" and then I set settings with intl.cpl

control.exe intl.cpl,,/f:"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\mui.xml"

The content of mui.xml is the following:

```
<gs:GlobalizationServices xmlns:gs="urn:longhornGlobalizationUnattend">
<!-- User List -->
<gs:UserList>
<gs:User UserID="Current" CopySettingsToSystemAcct="true" 
CopySettingsToDefaultUserAcct="true"/>
</gs:UserList>
</gs:GlobalizationServices>
```

After this I reboot the system and everything is fine.

Best regards

Comment: What do you exactly mean "everything is fine"? I tried to go the opposite direction, from an originally German install to English and so far I am very dissatisfied. More than half all system elements are still in German. For example, when searching for "Device Manager" in the search window nothing come up but "Geraetemanager" shows up. A very half-hearted implementation by Microsoft if you ask me. Even when reinstalling the whole OS I only can install it in German, which is the only language choice. If there is another way to install it from the get-go in English I would appreciate being shown